# Serialize a HashMap in java to pass it from server to client in java

Tags: java, client-server

I am writing a server/client application in Java. I do some data processing in the server side then store it in `HashMap`. What would the best way to pass the `HashMap` to the client ?

Comment: What kind of client? Also, what kind of data can you pass to the client? Objects (if so, just send the HashMap)? Strings? In this case, I suggest using a JSON-based approach.

Comment: Serialize it to JSON.

Comment: Are both the client and Server written in Java? and how are you communicating between the two, using http?

Comment: communication using sockets i just serialised the hashMap wrote it into a file and read the file in the client side

Comment: No need to write it into a file.

Comment: I changed it to your approach now @m0skit0 thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most straight-forward solution is to serialize/deserialize it using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`

```
try {
    ...
    final Map<A, B> yourMap = ...; // Map to send
    final OutputStream yourOutputStream = ...; // OutputStream where to send the map in case of network you get it from the Socket instance.
    final ObjectOutputStream mapOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(yourOutputStream);
    mapOutputStream.writeObject(yourMap);
    ...
} finally {
    outputStream.close();
}
```

And to receive it:

```
try {
    ...
    final InputStream yourInputStream = ...; // InputStream from where to receive the map, in case of network you get it from the Socket instance.
    final ObjectInputStream mapInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(yourInputStream);
    final Map<A, B> yourMap = (Map) mapInputStream.readObject();
    ...
} finally {
    mapInputStream.close();
}
```

Note that this doesn't require any external library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing:

First serialize the map to json by:

```
new JSONObject(map);
```

Other functions you can get from its documentation
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Then use a ajax call from client to populate the json data to display.

Like:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "your ajax url",
        type: "POST",
        data: myData,
        context: this,
        error: function () {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function () {
            //You can use your data here.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution depends largely on what protocol / communication you are using between server and client. However, json is very fashionable at the moment and allows all data to encoded to a string, which is usually then sent via http.

There are libraries to encode objects to json. However, it is also very easy to create a `String`:

```
String mapout = '{ ';
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
    mapout += "'" + entry.getKey() + "' : '" + entry.getValue() + ", ";

//remove trailing comma
if(mapout.length() > 2)
    mapout = mapout.substring(0,mapout.length - 2);

 mapout += " }";
```

If you are creating a lot of Json it is best to use a library, but this code does illustrate how easy json is to use and why it is fashionable atm.